# Questions about read_csv and str dtype

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large text file where the columns are of the following form:

```
1255 32627 some random stuff which might have numbers 1245
```

1.I would like to use `read_csv` to give me a data frame with three columns. The first two columns should be dtype uint32 and the third just has everything afterwards in a string. That is the line above should be split into `1255`, `32627` and `some random stuff which might have numbers 1245`. This for example does not do it but at least shows the dtypes:

```
    pd.read_csv("foo.txt", sep=' ', header=None, dtype={0:np.uint32, 1:np.uint32, 2:np.str})
```

2.My second question is about the `str` dtype.How much RAM does it use and if I know the max length of a string can I reduce that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is there a reason you need to use `pd.read_csv()`? The code below is straightforward and easily modifies your column values to your requirements.

   ```
   from numpy import uint32
   from csv import reader
   from pandas import DataFrame

   file = 'path/to/file.csv'
   with open(file, 'r') as f:
       r = reader(f)
       for row in r:
           column_1 = uint32(row[0])
           column_2 = uint32(row[1])
           column_3 = ' '.join([str(col) for col in row[2::]])

       data = [column_1, column_2, column_3]
       frame = DataFrame(data)
   ```
2. I don't understand the question. Do you expect your strings to be extremely long? A 32-bit Python installation is limited to a string 2-3GB long. A 64-bit installation is much *much* larger, limited only by the amount of RAM you can stuff into your system.

Comment: Thanks. No sorry I meant the strings may be very short (e.g. 2 chars) and an object uses many bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Series.str.cat method, documentation for which is available [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv("foo.txt", sep=' ', header=None)

# Create a new column which concatenates all columns
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.iloc[2:].apply(str).str.cat(sep = ' '),axis=1)
df = df[[0,1,'new']]
```

Not sure exactly what you mean by your second question but if you want to check the size of a string in memory you can use

```
import sys
print (sys.getsizeof('some string'))
```

Sorry, I have no idea how knowing the maximum length will help you in saving memory and whether that is even possible

Comment: This reads all the columns separately and then merges them. I was hoping you could avoid doing that.

Comment: The issue is that np.str is an object it seems.

Comment: There is no direct method in read_csv for achieving what you want directly, as far as I know.